# In general, should I write multiple versions of a code body in case a user is missing packages?

Tags: python, error-handling, runtime-error

Suppose that I'm building a Python program, and in the very beginning, I import two modules - **something**, which is included in the python libraries by default, and **somethingElse**, which isn't.

I have two nearly-identical functions, one that works without **somethingElse**, but also a second version that works even better with it. While ideally, people would just install the required dependencies, I'd prefer if there accessible to users whose machines/systems are incompatible with the **somethingElse** package.
*Example:*

```
try:
   import something
   import somethingElse
except ImportError:
   import something

if not ImportError:
   versionA()

else:
   versionB()
```

Is this good practice, or is there a better way to approach this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general it's better to have a pip `requirements.txt` file or `setup.py` that handles dependencies. However, if you need to do this for whatever reason, I think it would be better to have a single class that serves as a wrapper for either library and the consumer doesn't care which was imported. For example, in your module you'd have something like:

```
try:
    import better_lib

    class LibAPI(object):
        root_lib = better_lib
        def fizzle(self, *args, **kwargs):
            return self.root_lib.better_fizzle(*args, **kwargs)
        def mundun(self, n, x, **kwargs):
            floof = (n, x)
            return self.root_lib.better_mundun(floof, **kwargs)

except ImportError:
    import worse_lib

    class LibAPI(object):
        root_lib = worse_lib
        def fizzle(self, x, y, z, **kwargs):
            fizz = self.root_lib.worse_fizz(x, y)
            return self.root_lib.izzle(fizz, z, **kwargs)
        def mundun(self, *args, **kwargs):
            return self.root_lib.worse_mundun(*args, **kwargs)

lib_api = LibAPI()
```

That way even though the core libraries may be quite different, in your code you can interact with them in the same way (`lib_api.fizzle()` and `lib_api.mundun()`) since you've wrapped whatever differences there are in a single unified wrapper. It's better to have all this in one single place instead of checking which library has been imported in all sorts of places littered throughout your code. You can still introspect which library was used if you absolutely need to by checking what `lib_api.root_lib` is.

Comment: Nice! I was going to suggest monkey patching but this is way better.